# An algorithm in which the threshold value is not constant but changes according to peak position

Tags: vb.net, algorithm, threshold

```
If RByte > Val(txtThreshold.Text) And fTmr = False Then
        TCount = 0
        tmr.Enabled = True
    End If

    If RByte > Val(txtThreshold.Text) And fTmr = True And TCount > 5 Then
        tmr.Enabled = False

        'calculate HB 
        lblHB.Text = CInt(600 / TCount)
```

Here     `rbyte is input data` ,    `ftmr is boolean` and `tcount is timer bit of type integer`. `txtThreshold.text takes a threshold value from user` but I want to auto set the threshold. According to second if statement (the `tcount` at which the `rbyte` becomes greater than threshold will be used to get bpm), the bpm values I'll be getting will be constant and highly depend upon threshold set by the user.

I wanted an algorithm where threshold could vary according to the data points and where it wouldn't remain static (like standard deviation for threshold) but change accordingly which might give variable beats per minute(`lblHB.Text`).

Comment: Not sure I understand why STD (or C*STD for some constant C) won't work for your case.

Comment: @amit i know it should work but i'm getting a constant value for bpm. i want values to change from person to person

Comment: What is "person" here? a user? some kind of entry? You are not clear...

Comment: @amit i'm using a custom stethoscope which is used to measure heart beats of a person. the data is amplified, filtered and is sent to program in form of byte. so, if i get 72 bpm(heart beats per minute) for one person, i should get some other value when the stethoscope is used on other people but i get the same value for everybody(even if they intentionally breath heavily.)

Comment: And what is the input format? I mean, do you get multiple values per person? (How much?) Do you have history of this user?

Comment: input is taken as bytes and stored in array of bytes. right now the value of bpm remains constant for all users(around 100 which is technically incorrect because for normal person it should be around 72). i want the bpm to vary. these values(bpm) are not stored anywhere, they are just displayed in a textbox.

Comment: what is the use of `tcount`.. i guess you are getting value 100 because.. you go inside second `if` when TCount is `6` and 600/6 = 100. Do you want a random value in txtThreashold.Text ?

Comment: @AshishNegi tcount is the counter bit(it runs from 0 to 500 till rcount>txtThreshold.text). when value of rbyte is detected as larger than txtThreshold.txt, the value of tcount at that instant is used for bpm measurement. after that tcount resets and starts the counter again(yes  tcount runs from 0 to 6 and then starts again and hence constant 100 is obtained.) but at times(i don't know how..) tcount goes till 10 and then resets which gives a bpm of 60....but it happens for just a second. other times it is stuck at 100 even when no peak is observed.

Comment: @kal so you want some algorithm to generate txtThrshold.text value ? and what would be the input for this algorithm ? you headline says : `according to peak position`. what is peak position ? what other inputs are there that you can/need to give to this algorithm. ?? Edit your question with them also.

Comment: @AshishNegi i've mentioned that rbyte is the input (this is the only input i'm getting). when i plot rbyte wrt time then i get wave forms wherein i get peaks at short intervals. i'm using txt.threshold.text as a threshold value to find the peak(if peak is obseved above this value then rbyte>txtThreshold.text) . the graph is similar to ECG( cardio waveform) graph.

Comment: @kai What about `threshold = max(max-threahold-limit, avg-input-value-till-now)` ?